# BASH check if today is 1st day of month

Tags: bash, date

I have a bash script and I need it to fulfill some conditions if it is 1st day of month.
I have written this code

```
ifStart=`date '+%d'`
if [$ifStart == 01]
then
test=`/bin/date --date='1 day ago' +'%Y-%m'`
echo $test
fi
```

I expect it to show 2013-03 today, but I get an errormessage:
Line 2 command not found.

```
test=`/bin/date --date='1 day ago' +'%Y-%m'`
```

this part works well without if.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The command that's not being found is actually due to your if statement. You need spaces:

```
if [ $ifStart == 01 ]
```

Otherwise `[$ifStart` will be interpreted as a command.